What does 言っておく prepare for?

後で詳しく説明するかもしれないのと、彼を安心させたいから、だまし取ってないと言っておいてください。
彼をだましたいから、だまし取ってないと言っておいてください。

I understand that ~ておく means "to express the act of preparing for a certain purpose." For #2, I understand that 言っておく is to prepare for 彼をだましたい。But for #1, What does 言っておく prepare for?

I'm just curious about the context of what's being said.  Who says something like your second sentence?  彼をだましたいから、だまし取ってないと言っておいてください.

So what does 言っておく prepare for in the first sentence?

I'd still like some context to understand what the second sentence is about.  Right now it sounds strange to me; perhaps it's something that a supervillain would say.  But context would be helpful (not for a translation, that's straight forward, but just to make sense of why someone would say that).

I wouldn't say you should always think of ～ておく as necessarily meaning preparing for something concrete.  Particularly with this 言っておく.  It can mean like "Just so you know, ~" or "For future reference, ~".  Many places in my Japanese Bible, Jesus will say something like "I tell you the truth: ~", or "Truly I tell you: ~", and it is often translated as (はっきり)言っておくが、....

@A.Ellett sorry for confusing you. The context is, someone only said だまし取ってないと言っておいてください. If he's evil, probably #2 is what he meant. #1 otherwise.

That is one of the ways to use it, yes. I suspect your confusion comes from your materials not teaching you about the other ways it can be used, and to understand that, we need to go a little deeper, starting with how it's used as a 五段 verb.
As a 五段 verb, 置{お}く is used to say something was put down somewhere, or set to one side.
What you're seeing this used as, is as a 助動詞{じょどうし} , also known as helper verbs, and auxiliary verbs, in English linguistic circles, in this case one used after the て form of verbs.
As a 助動詞, it expresses similar sentiments, suggesting a given action is done, in preparation of things to come, kinda like saying, “I’ll pocket this, just in case”.

チェックしておきますね~
I’ll check it out, just to be sure

In casual use, you’ll see some squish the て and お together, to make -とく.

チェックしておく

↓

チェックしとく

Additionally, it can be used to suggest something was left the way it was, just in case someone else wanted it that way, which is likely the usage you saw, in that sentence. Grammatically it functions like a く五段.

I fixed some formatting, but I also think that it does not matter here if this verb is 五段 or 一段 or 二段 etc. Classification into 一段／二段／五段 can just as well be applied to auxiliary verbs and suffixes (and some suffixes have their own unique conjugation). So you may want a term "independent verb" or something similar.

So what does 言っておく prepare for in #1?

@Arfrever I think the point of the 五段 bit was to distinguish the use as an ordinary verb from use as an auxiliary (i.e. following te-form).

言っておく is not preparing for anything per se.  It's conveying the idea of "let's get this said so the guy can feel safe."
We don't have anything really comparable in English.
But I would say だまし取ってないと言っておいてください should/could be translated as something along the lines of

Make sure to tell him that we're not out to trick him.

